# Display form within a custom field?

Tags: 7, entities

I've created a module that has a 'form builder' on the admin side.  Once the form has been created, I store the form array in the database.  Then on the front end I've created a custom field that pulls the form array from the database and displays it as part of a node.  Here is the pseudo-code to show my thinking:

```
- Create form via admin side and store form array in database
- Create node with custom field, choose which form you wish to display
- Set url alias on the node
- When user views url, display the form as part of the node
```

The problem I have is that when I complete the form on the front end and press submit, nothing happens.  Looking at the html, it doesn't have a `<form>` tag, presumably because it's part of a node and not a hook_form.

So, I'm wondering if it's possible to display a submittable form as a custom field?  Or do I need to find another way around this?

**Edit:**  I'm using the following code to display the form:

```
function mantis_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {

    $element = array();

    switch($display['type']) {
        case 'mantisform_default': {

            // Retrieve the form from the database
            $form_data = mantis_retrieve_form_data($items[0]['mantis_form_id'], 'display');

            $element[]['#markup'] = drupal_render($form_data);

        }
    }
    return $element;
}
```

**Edit**:  $form_data structure can be seen here http://pastebin.com/JfeNGBGA  and $element is here http://pastebin.com/HU5NSHd5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out.  The reason the form wasn't submitting was because I wasn't calling drupal_get_form.  It seems that drupal_get_form carries out a lot of essential processing that allows the form to function.  Simply creating a form array and calling drupal_render is not enough to create a functional form.

The solution was to create an implementation of `hook_form` and retrieve my form data from the database:

```
function mantis_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $data = db_select('mantis_forms', 'f')
    ->fields('f', array('form_data'))
    ->condition('id', $form_state['build_info']['args'][0], '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchField();

    if($data) {
        $data = unserialize($data);

        // If we're on the admin side then disable the submit button
        if($form_state['build_info']['args'][1] == 'admin') {
            $data['form_wrapper']['submit_form']['#disabled'] = true;
        } else {
            // If we're on the front end then enable the submit button and remove the optional fields
            $data['form_wrapper']['submit_form']['#disabled'] = false;
            array_slice($data, 1, 1);
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

And then amend the hook_formatter_view to use drupal_get_form:

```
function mantis_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {

    $element = array();

    switch($display['type']) {
        case 'mantisform_default': {

            $form_data = drupal_get_form('mantis_form', $items[0]['mantis_form_id'], 'display');

            $element[]['#markup'] = drupal_render($form_data);

        }
    }
return $element;
}
```

Comment: drupal_get_form before drupal_render. Good one, bye !

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your field handler, node tpl.php or field tpl.php and use drupal_render($yourform), it's the cleanest solution I see.

Comment: I've edited the question to show the code I am using to display the form.  I am using drupal_render already, so wondering if there is a difference between using drupal render in a template file as oppose to using it in hook_field_formatter_view?

Comment: What give your dpm($form_data) and dpm($element) ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've added the structure of form data to pastebin http://pastebin.com/JfeNGBGA

Comment: Output for $element http://pastebin.com/HU5NSHd5